# Rendering a different action, where the second action needs more params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to achieve something like the following:

```
  def some_function
    redirect_to :action=> show ,:id=>current_user.id
  end

  // this will throw an error that id is nil
  def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

What can I try to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should redirect to an url, not to an action. Do something like this:

```
redirect_to user_url(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

change you routing definition

```
match 'show/:id' => 'Controller#Action'
```

Then use code like this :

```
def some_function
  redirect_to "/show/#{@user.id}"
end
```